# How to build custom calendar in android studio?

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, sdk

currently I am working on a app where I have to build a custom calendar daywise attendance. Now I want to highlight the dates for absent, present and leave and I also want to disable navigation button for next and previous button. Can anyone please tell me how could I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I used calendarView but I could not proceed further. Please tell how can I build this.

Comment: You're basically asking someone to develop a complex app for you. You need to do your own research and ask more specific questions when you're able to show us a proper code sample of what you tried so far

Comment: Can u please tell from where I can start? I tried every library and tutorial but none of them helped them.